# array index blows up obj c

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I am writing an iPhone app in Xcode 4.6.3.

I don't really know how to ask this question, but during operation, an array index goes from 0, which is hardcoded in a method, to 58911 for some reason. The chain is:

```
- (void)syncInitialState
{
    [self syncState:0]; //value starts hardcoded here
}
```

then:

```
- (void)syncState:(int)index
{
    self.state = [macrostate getState:index];
    [self syncState];
}
```

in Macrostate:

```
- (NPState *)getState:(int)index
{
    int *singleArray = {&index};
    NSPointerArray *pointerArray = [self subsetFromIntArray:singleArray];
    return (__bridge NPState *)[pointerArray pointerAtIndex:0]; //only one object
}
```

finally:

```
- (NSPointerArray *)subsetFromIntArray:(int *)intArray
{
    NSPointerArray *subset = [NSPointerArray strongObjectsPointerArray];
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(intArray); i++) {
        [subset addPointer:[pointerArrayOfStates pointerAtIndex:intArray[i]]]; //fails
    }
    return subset;
}
```

Obviously it fails because 58911 is outside the bounds of the pointer array. I have never seen this before. Thanks for reading.

It might help to know that the error is: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '** -[NSConcretePointerArray pointerAtIndex:]: attempt to access pointer at index 58911 beyond bounds 4' ** First throw call stack: (0x1caa012 0x10e7e7e 0x1ca9deb 0xb1c1ab 0xd8ae 0xd7a5 0x47c6 0x485e 0x567f 0x5d95 0x2d3f 0x10d1c7 0x10d232 0x5c3d5 0x5c76f 0x5c905 0x65917 0x29c5 0x29157 0x29747 0x2a94b 0x3bcb5 0x3cbeb 0x2e698 0x1c05df9 0x1c05ad0 0x1c1fbf5 0x1c1f962 0x1c50bb6 0x1c4ff44 0x1c4fe1b 0x2a17a 0x2bffc 0x26fd 0x2625) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Don't add the error as a comment, update your question with it so it is easier to read.

Comment: C is not Java.  `sizeof(intArray)` returns the size of the pointer, not the size of the array.  That expression will always return 4 (for systems with 4-byte pointers).  If your array is smaller you'll be addressing air.

Comment: @HotLicks Isn't C a little confusing in that `sizeof(array)` where that is an actual stack-allocated array in the current scope will actually give you its size? (Although probably not the element count.)

Comment: @millimoose - C is *a lot* confusing, in that regards and many others.  (Though one has to remember that it's a rather ancient language.)  (And one wonders what excuse Java has, for it's only slightly less numerous traps.)

Comment: @HotLicks I'd wager a good bunch is "IBM's contributions to the JDK".

Comment: @rmaddy: ok. I'll do that in future.

Comment: @arkaeologic You can edit your question now. No need to wait for the future to do it.

Comment: @millimoose -- Not sure what you mean by that, but there are (easily) a dozen things in the .class file format that could have been changed to make life easier for everyone but weren't.  Eg, the limit to the size of an individual method is due primarily to the limitation of the offset fields in the debug table, but this could have been easily versioned.  (But I suppose that Sun didn't want to make that fix because their verifier was so slow and memory-hungry compared to the IBM iSeries "Classic" one, and larger methods would have made them look bad.)

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Caleb Essentially, I have an array of previously defined objects that I want to put into another array for use in the program. The idea is to have states. For example, an object could have two states: Up and Down. The original array would be [Up, Down]. If I want a string of states, I want to call it like getStates([0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0]) for example. For brevity, this require an array of ints of which the length would have to be known. I am currently using a shameless hack having found no better way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `sizeof` to get the length of the `int` array. You need to add a "length" parameter to your `subsetFromIntArray:` method and use that instead of `sizeof`.

Comment: Great. My problem then becomes building in a whole chain of arguments passed from one method to the next just to know the size of the original array. Thanks C. @rmaddy: I guess the huge value was some size in bytes then.

Comment: Sorry, but although you solution is good and probably would work in other cases, it is difficult to implement in my case. The array length is dynamic and would have to be known from the beginning anyway. What I really need is len(list).

Comment: There is no such thing as "len(list)" where "list" is a plain old pointer representing a C-array of unknown length. One possible option though is to make your array "null terminated" much like a standard C-string. You still can't directly get the length but at least you can increment the pointer until you get a NULL value.